# PHP - Read from row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, row

I am trying to make a working script with LOGIN and REGISTER, and i can't read user information after he logged in.

I am using cookies to make sure he is "online" and he is, everything is working good.

The problem is that i can't read his information, don't know why.

```
$sql = "SELECT mod FROM korisnici where user = "'.$_COOKIES['username'].'"";
```

And if i put `cookies['username']` instead of `admin(real username)`, still doesnt work.

I am trying to get only MOD.

Comment: You have syntax errors. Take a look how you use single and double quotes.

Comment: Your PHP error log is telling you about your syntax error.  Always check the error log.  Also, your code is wide open to SQL injection, you should use prepared statements with query parameters instead.

Comment: There is no errors,

this is code: http://prntscr.com/e56ial
this is output: http://prntscr.com/e56hp2

Comment: @НиколаР.: `"There is no errors"` - Wrong.  Just because you're not *checking* for errors doesn't mean there *are no* errors.  Ignoring a problem doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think your apostrophe aren't at the right place:

```
$sql = "SELECT mod FROM korisnici where user = '" . $_COOKIES['username']. "'";
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/e56ial take a look

Comment: this is not the code you posted...